# Cumulative sum of the smallest neighbors in the previous row in a Numpy array

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following code snippet, which essentially does the following:
Given a 2d numpy array, `arr`, compute `sum_arr`  as follow:
$$sum\_arr[i, j] = \begin{cases}
    arr[i, j] + min(sum\_arr[i - 1, j-1:j+2]), &i > 0\\ arr[i, j], &i = 0\end{cases}$$ 
(reasonable indices for `j - 1 : j + 2` of course, all within `0` and `w`)

Here's my implementation:

```
import numpy as np

h, w = 1000, 1000 # Shape of the 2d array
arr = np.arange(h * w).reshape((h, w)) 

sum_arr = arr.copy()

def min_parent(i, j):
    min_index = j    
    if j > 0:
        if sum_arr[i - 1, j - 1] < sum_arr[i - 1, min_index]:
            min_index = j - 1
    if j < w - 1:
        if sum_arr[i - 1, j + 1] < sum_arr[i - 1, min_index]:
            min_index = j + 1    
    return (i - 1, min_index)


for i, j in np.ndindex((h - 1, w)):
    sum_arr[i + 1, j] += sum_arr[min_parent(i + 1, j)]
```

And here's the problem: this code snippet takes way too long to execute for only 1e6 operations (About 5s on average on my machine)

What is a better way of implementing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- first, your problem is example of [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). [Here some tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50974371/efficient-dynamic-programming-using-python) how to approach problem in python
- your solution calculate each table cell separately. But function `min_parent()` use data only from previous row, so you can calculate row by row (and `numpy` is designed to fast operations on vectors)
- i am using like you range `<j - 1 : j + 2)` but check if task don't need `<j - 1, j + 2>`

Example code

```
assert(w >= 2) # if not, you should handle w == 1 in special way

def vectorized_solution(arr, h):
    sum_arr = arr.copy()
    for i in range(1, h):
        parent = sum_arr[i - 1, :]
        sum_arr[i, 0] += min(parent[0], parent[1])
        sum_arr[i, 1:-1] += np.minimum.reduce([parent[0:-2], parent[1:-1], parent[2:]])
        sum_arr[i, -1] += min(parent[-2], parent[-1])
    return sum_arr
```

Comment: Storing parent seems unnecessary given we could replace `parent[j]` with `sum_arr[i - 1, j]`. Also a (slightly, just about 0.04s for h, w = 1000 in the given code) faster vectorization could be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53889590/calls-to-constant-time-function-iterating-through-numpy-array-results-in-very-sl/53890258#53890258